# asp.net vnext camelCase JSON serialization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Anyone knows how to set the camelCase JSON serialization for asp.net vnext? In `Startup.cs` I have two functions.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {}
```

How do I set JSON.net to use camelCase? In previous asp.net versions I had a `GlobalConfiguration` object that I could change like this

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

// Replace the default JsonFormatter with our custom one
var index = config.Formatters.IndexOf(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
config.Formatters[index] = new JsonCamelCaseFormatter();
```

---UPDATE

Thanks Kiran. Here is the updated solution that works with the current version of asp.net.

```
services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
  int position = options.OutputFormatters.FindIndex(f =>
                        f.Instance is JsonOutputFormatter);

  var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
  {
         ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
  };
  var formatter = new JsonOutputFormatter();
  formatter.SerializerSettings = settings;

  options.OutputFormatters.Insert(position, formatter);
});
```

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393466/how-to-add-camelcasepropertynamescontractresolver-in-startup-cs